# Rename x for y with loop in batch file

Tags: windows, loops, batch-file, rename

I'm having problems with string literals in renaming files:

I have a number of files that contain the substring x and I want to substitute them for y which may occur in any part of the filename.

```
cheese.txt
Sarah_cheese_Parker.txt
cheese_Brookes.txt
```

should become:

```
Louise.txt
Sarah_Louise_Parker.txt
Louise_Brookes.txt

set x="cheese"
set y="Louise"
```

This is what I have so far

```
for %%f in (x*.txt) do 
(
    echo %%f
    call :processit "%%f"
)
goto finished

:processit
ren x%i%.txt y%i%.txt

goto :finished

:finished
dir *.txt /b
```

I'm not worried about complications with % in the filename.

Comment: The left parenthesis needs to be on the same line as the DO. Use the `SET` command to do string replacement before the rename.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The batch file should be stored in directory containing all the *.txt files and executed with a double click.

```
@echo off
for /F "eol=| delims=" %%I in ('dir "*cheese*.txt" /A-D /B 2^>nul') do call :RenameFile "%%I"
set "NewName="
pause
goto :EOF

:RenameFile
set "NewName=%~nx1"
set "NewName=%NewName:cheese=Louise%"
ren "%~1" "%NewName%"
goto :EOF
```

The command **DIR** searches

- just for files because of `/A-D` (not attribute directory)
- only in current directory as not using additionally `/S`
- for *.txt files containing `cheese` and
- outputs in bare format because of `/B` the names of the found files with file extension, but without path.

The **DIR** command line is executed by **FOR** in a separate command process in background which captures the output of this command process (= command **DIR**) written to handle **STDOUT**.

A possible error output by **DIR** on not finding in directory any file matching the wildcard pattern to handle **STDERR** is suppressed by redirecting it with `2>nul` to device **NUL**. Read also the Microsoft article about [Using Command Redirection Operators](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx) for an explanation of `2>nul`. The redirection operator `>` must be escaped with caret character `^` on **FOR** command line to be interpreted as literal character when Windows command interpreter processes this command line before executing command **FOR** which executes the embedded `dir` command line with using a separate command process started in background.

The command **FOR** processes each line captured from output of **DIR**. The default behavior of **FOR** to ignore lines starting with `;` is disabled by option `eol=|`. The character `|` can't be used in a file/folder name and so can't be at begin of a file/folder name. The default behavior of **FOR** to split up each line on horizontal tabs and spaces into substrings is disabled by option `delims=` specifying an empty list of delimiters. So **FOR** really assigns each file name with file extension, but without path to loop variable `I`.

It is important here to run **FOR** on a captured list of file names instead of letting **FOR** itself search recursively for the TXT files as otherwise it could happen during the file renames that some TXT files are skipped because of the directory entry changes during the loop iterations.

For each file name the subroutine `RenameFile` is called with passing the full file name as first argument enclosed in double quotes to the subroutine. The double quotes are necessary to process correct also the file names on containing a space or one of these characters `` &()[]{}^=;!'+,`~ `` in file name or file path.

A subroutine is used instead of doing the remaining code directly in the **FOR** loop as this would require usage of delayed environment variable expansion which would cause problems if file/folder names of the processed files contain by chance one or more exclamation marks.

In the subroutine `RenameFile` the name of the current file without path is assigned to environment variable `NewName`.

Next a string substitution is applied on file name to replace case-insensitive **all** occurrences of `cheese` by `Louise`.

Then the file rename is executed with specifying the file to rename and the new name with file extension without path as required by command **REN**.

The command **ECHO** could be inserted left to `ren` to run the batch file first for just checking if the file renames would be done as expected.

The **DIR** option `/S` could be added after `/B` to search additionally also recursive in all subdirectories of current directory for *.txt files with `cheese` in file name. In this case **DIR** would output all file names with full path. But the batch file as written would work nevertheless correct.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `call /?`
- `dir /?`
- `echo /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `pause /?`
- `ren /?`
- `set /?`

See also [Where does GOTO :EOF return to?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37518000/3074564)

Answer (score 1):

This code do what you want. Note that `*%x%*.txt` is the right wild-card for "files that contain the substring x which may occur in any part of the filename".

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "x=cheese"
set "y=Louise"

for %%f in (*%x%*.txt) do (
    echo %%f
    call :processit "%%f"
)
goto finished

:processit
set "name=%~1"
ren "%~1" "!name:%x%=%y%!"
exit /B

:finished
dir *.txt /b
```

The keypoint in this solution is that the replacement of one substring by another one can only be done *in a variable*, so it is necessary to assign the `%1` subroutine parameter to the `name` variable.

The second point is that in order to replace one substring by another one, *when both strings are stored in variables*, you need to use a *standard `%expansion%`* to first expand the `x` and `y` substrings, and then a *delayed `!expansion!`* to perform the replacement in `name` variable; this is achieved in this line:

```
ren "%~1" "!name:%x%=%y%!"
```

A final point is that you don't really need a subroutine in this case, so the final code could be simpler:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "x=cheese"
set "y=Louise"

for %%f in (*%x%*.txt) do (
    echo %%f
    set "name=%%f"
    ren "%%f" "!name:%x%=%y%!"
)
dir *.txt /b
```